# jquery animation of circular list

Tags: jquery

I have a vertical list of li elements that I want to rotate such that it appears as it is on a roller (like icons on a slot machine or numbers on a combination lock). I can create this by simply adding something like:

```
$('#list li:first').before($('#list li:last'));
```

Problem is sometimes the list is exactly the number of visible elements in length and what I would like to retain is the last element sliding off the bottom and concurrently sliding onto the top to create the look of a circular list. One thought was to duplicate the list elements if its length was less than the visible length and animating the margin-top property of each li element to slide down but then I have duplicates of each list element, is there a better way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Rotation function based on Alex Ball's response below.

```
function rotate(direction){
    var firstElem = $('#list ul li:first');
    var lastElem = $('#list ul li:last');
    var elemHeight =  firstElem.height();

    if(direction == 'down') {
        firstElem.animate({'marginTop': '+=' + elemHeight + 'px'}, 500, 'linear', function(){
            $(this).css({'margin-top':0}).before(lastElem);         
        });
    }

    if(direction == 'up') {
        firstElem.animate({'marginTop': '-=' + elemHeight + 'px'}, 500, 'linear', function(){
            lastElem.after($(this));
            $(this).css({'margin-top':0});
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example (I've used the idea of slot Machine because is fanny)

I started with some div container and list (li) of images, but the idea is valid for other types.

the rotete JS:

```
function rotate(id, n){

    console.log(id);    

     $('#'+id+' ul li:first').animate({'margin-top': '-='+$(this).height()+'px'}, 400, 'linear', function(){

          $(this).css({'margin-top':0}).parent().append($(this));

          i++;

          console.log('id: '+id+' i: '+i+' n: '+n);

          if(i < n) rotate(id, n);

     });

}
```

See in action [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A2dau/)

Comment: Love your style. Thank you very much, works great. Will append my resulting rotate function to the original post. Still can't get around having to duplicate elements on smaller lists but the rotation functionality is perfect.