# HTML list in circular queue fashion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a scrollable list of items , when last item is scrolled to top i want first item to follow it on the next index along with all remaining items on relative indexes, any idea to implement it using jquery?

Comment: Are you asking for vertical carousel that runs indefenitely?

Comment: I think these two links will be helpful to you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515034/jquery-animation-of-circular-list

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843629/create-a-circular-list-with-jquery

Comment: its similar to 360 degree slideshow..Am i rit.

Comment: @Upvote, its not like 360 slide show as i required.

Comment: @prasanna may u show some working example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your requirement using one the below example:
[Codepen example url](https://codepen.io/RahulKesharwani/pen/wEYpJg) 
[image]

```js
const srart_pos = 90.75;
const item_count = 13;
const s = 0.52 * Math.PI / 180; //Вычислим угол смещения

var pos = [];
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
 

function allocationItems() {
  var i;
  var pp = elem[6].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('data-img'); 
  document.getElementById("pic").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+pp+"')"; 
  document.getElementById("pic").className = "img-box";
  pos[0] = srart_pos;
  for (i = 1; i < item_count; i++) {
    pos[i] = pos[i - 1] - 0.2;
    last_pos=pos[i];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < item_count+1; i++) {
    elem[i].style.left = 240 + 250 * Math.sin(pos[i]) + 'px';
    elem[i].style.top = 240 + 250 * Math.cos(pos[i]) + 'px';
  }
}  

allocationItems();

function animation(args, flag) { // некоторые аргументы определим на будущее
    var $ = {
        radius: 250, // радиус окружности 
        speed: 10 // скорость/задержка ( в js это мс, например 10 мс = 100 кадров в секунду)
    };
    var e = elem;
    document.getElementById("pic").className = "hide";    
    function animate(draw, duration, callback) {
        var start = performance.now();
        requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
            // определить, сколько прошло времени с начала анимации
            var timePassed = time - start;
            console.log(time, start)
            // возможно небольшое превышение времени, в этом случае зафиксировать конец
            if (timePassed > duration)
                timePassed = duration;
            // нарисовать состояние анимации в момент timePassed
            draw(timePassed);
            // если время анимации не закончилось - запланировать ещё кадр
            if (timePassed < duration) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            } else callback();
        });
    }
    animate(function (timePassed) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < item_count; i++) {
            e[i].style.left = 240 + $.radius * Math.sin(pos[i]) + 'px';
            e[i].style.top = 240 + $.radius * Math.cos(pos[i]) + 'px';
            if (flag) {
                pos[i] += s; 
            } else {
                pos[i] -= s; 
            }
        }   /* callback function */
    }, 400, function changeItems() {
        var list = document.getElementById('list');
        var ch = flag ? list.firstElementChild : list.lastElementChild
        ch.remove();
        if (flag) {
          list.appendChild(ch);
        } else {
          list.insertBefore(ch, list.firstChild);
        }
        allocationItems();
    });
}
```

```css
$border-color: #a2c0d9;
$background-color: #4682b4;
$font-color: #dae6ef;
$hover-color: white;

body {
  background-color: $background-color;
}

a:hover,
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.c-menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 440px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

%gradient-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
}

.top {
  @extend %gradient-box;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(70, 130, 180, 1) 0%,
    rgba(70, 130, 180, 0) 100%
  );
}

.bottom {
  @extend %gradient-box;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(70, 130, 180, 0) 0%,
    rgba(70, 130, 180, 1) 100%
  );
}

.img-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 177px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 82px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity, 2s;
 }

.hide {
  @extend .img-box;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity, .5s;
}

.items-list {
  position: absolute;
  left: -400px;
  top: -101px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 498px;
  border: 2px solid $border-color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 70px;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: font-size 1s;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:nth-child(7) {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    transition: font-size .5s;
  }
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: $font-color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    top: 4px;
  }
  &:nth-child(7):before{
    top: 10px;
    //box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px yellow, 
    //            0 0 0 4px deeppink,      
    //            0 0 0 6px darkorange,
    //            0 0 0 8px #8014ff;
  }
  a {
    color: $font-color;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    &:hover {
      color: $hover-color;
      transition: color 0.5s ;
    }
  }
  &:nth-child(2),
  &:nth-child(3),
  &:nth-child(11),
  &:nth-child(12) {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 60px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: $font-color;
  transform: scale(3, 1);
  user-select: none;
  &:hover {
    color: $hover-color;
    transition: color 0.5s;
  }
}

.prev {
  top: 110px;
}

.next {
  bottom: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-menu">
    <div id="list" class="items-list">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://sass-scss.ru" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://sass-scss.ru&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               Sass: Документация на русском языке
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.color-hex.com/" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=http://www.color-hex.com&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               Color Hex Color Codes
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://webref.ru/" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://webref.ru&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               WebReference
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://www.w3schools.com&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               W3Schools Online Web Tutorials
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://learn.javascript.ru/" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://learn.javascript.ru&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               Современный учебник Javascript
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://caniuse.com" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://caniuse.com&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://css-tricks.com/" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://css-tricks.com&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               CSS-Tricks
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://codepen.io" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://codepen.io&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               CodePen
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://unicode-table.com" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://unicode-table.com&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               Таблица символов Юникода®
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a ref="https://fontawesome.com/" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://fontawesome.com&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               Font Awesome
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://ru.vuejs.org/index.html" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=https://vuejs.org&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               Vue.js
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://php.net/manual/ru/intro-whatis.php" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=http://php.net&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               PHP: Что такое PHP? - Manual
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.sql.ru/" data-img="https://eu1.searchpreview.de/preview?s=http://www.sql.ru&ua=Firefox&ver=1003&opts=111" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
               SQL.ru - все про SQL
            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="btn prev" onClick="animation({}, 1);">˄</div>
    <div id="pic" class="img-box"></div>
    <div class="btn next" onClick="animation({}, 0);">˅</div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is index to using javascript only, and all the element moves in circler direction.